# How can I create ViewModel and inject repository to it with dagger 2?

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-2

I try understanding ViewModel. I create ViewModel:

```
public class UsersViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public UsersViewModel(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> loadAll() {
        return usersRepository.getAll();
    }

}
```

But I not understand 2 things:

1. How can I inject `UsersRepository`  to this `VievModel`? When I used presenter I can create it with dagger 2 like this:

> ```
> @Module
> public class PresentersModule {
>
>     @Singleton
>     @Provides
>     UsersPresenter provideUsersPresenter(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
>         return new UsersPresenter(usersRepository);
>     }
> }
> ```

but how can I do it with `ViewModel`? Like this?

```
@Module
public class ViewModelsModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    UsersViewModel provideUsersViewModel(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        return new UsersViewModel(usersRepository);
    }
}
```

2. How can I get this ViewModel in fragment? With presenter I can this:

   presenter = MyApplication.get().getAppComponent().getUsersPresenter();

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ViewModel` is created via `ViewModelProvider` that uses a `ViewModelFactory` to create the instances. You can't inject ViewModels directly, instead you should use a custom factory like below

```
@Singleton
public class DaggerViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

@Inject
public DaggerViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
    this.creators = creators;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
    Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
    if (creator == null) {
        for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                creator = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (creator == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
    }
    try {
        return (T) creator.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Then you need a module for the dagger that creates the view model factory and view models itself.

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
@Binds
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(DaggerViewModelFactory factory);

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(VideoListViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel provideVideoListViewModel(VideoListViewModel videoListViewModel);

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(PlayerViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel providePlayerViewModel(PlayerViewModel playerViewModel);

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(PlaylistViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel providePlaylistViewModel(PlaylistViewModel playlistViewModel);

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(PlaylistDetailViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel providePlaylistDetailViewModel(PlaylistDetailViewModel playlistDetailViewModel);
}
```

`ViewModelKey` file is like this

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

Now to get your view model in the activity or fragment simply inject the view model factory and then use that factory to create the view model instances

```
public class PlayerActivity extends BaseActivity {
     @Inject DaggerViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;
     PlayerViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(PlayerViewModel.class);

}
```

To inject anything to your ViewModel like the repository simply use Constructor Injection.

```
public class PlayerViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private VideoRepository videoRepository;
    private AudioManager audioManager;


    @Inject
    public PlayerViewModel(VideoRepository videoRepository, AudioManager audioManager) {
         this.videoRepository = videoRepository;
         this.audioManager = audioManager;

    }
}
```

Check out the fully working example from here https://github.com/alzahm/VideoPlayer, Also I learned many of the dagger stuff from google samples, you can check them out as well.

Comment: Looking at this I seriously question whether this has anything to do with dependency injection. Calling get(PlayerViewModel.class) completely negates the purpose of DI which is to allow for testability.

Answer (score 2):

Dagger2 required you to create `ViewModelModule` and do the binding to your `ViewModels`

I know you are asking about Dagger2, but if you are starting a new project, maybe you can check out `Koin` which provides a lightweight injection.

I've used it in some of my production apps and it works fine with lesser lines of code.

You can just declare in your module like

```
viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) }
```

Then in your activities / fragments / classes (you need to extend `KoinComponent`), just write

```
val myViewModel : MyViewModel by viewModel()
```

It will handle the creation itself.

For more information can refer

https://insert-koin.io/

https://start.insert-koin.io/#/getting-started/koin-for-android?id=android-viewmodel

Comment: Yes, Koin more simple than Dagger

Comment: And what do you mean by "lightweight injection"? BTW,  Koin is a service locator

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that should make this more straightforward and way cleaner, no multibindings or factory boilerplate needed, while also giving the ability to further parametrise the `ViewModel` at runtime:
https://github.com/radutopor/ViewModelFactory

```
@ViewModelFactory
class UserViewModel(@Provided repository: Repository, userId: Int) : ViewModel() {

    val greeting = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        val user = repository.getUser(userId)
        greeting.value = "Hello, $user.name"
    }    
}
```

In the view:

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var userViewModelFactory2: UserViewModelFactory2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user)
        appComponent.inject(this)

        val userId = intent.getIntExtra("USER_ID", -1)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, userViewModelFactory2.create(userId))
            .get(UserViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.greeting.observe(this, Observer { greetingText ->
            greetingTextView.text = greetingText
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows you to inject dependencies into ViewModels and Workers without factories. Instead, it uses static methods.

**Injecting the Graph into a class**

This line can be used in the init block or the onCreate method (Example ViewModel at the bottom)

```
    Injector.getComponent().inject(this)
```

**BaseApplication**

```
    class BaseApplication : Application() {
    
        lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent
    
        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()

            INSTANCE = this

            applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent
                .builder()
                //Add your modules
                .build()
        }
    
        companion object {
            private var INSTANCE: BaseApplication? = null
    
            @JvmStatic
            fun get(): BaseApplication= INSTANCE!!
        }
    }
```

**Injector**

```
    class Injector private constructor() {
        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            fun getComponent(): ApplicationComponent = BaseApplication.get().applicationComponent
        }
    }
```

**That's it!**

Request injection like usual in your ApplicationComponent

**ApplicationComponent**

```
Singleton
@Component(modules = [add your modules])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(someViewModel: SomeViewModel)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
    class SomeViewModel : ViewModel(){

        @Inject
        lateinit var someClass: SomeClass //In your case, userRepository: UserRepository

        init{
            Injector.getComponent().inject(this)
        }
    }
```